# Why does voltage jump up with a rectifier circuit?

Tags: ac, voltage-divider, rectifier

I've got a need to measure the integral of voltage with respect to time.

I'm measuring a 25V AC power source through one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FVVSYYH) voltage dividers to get it down to a workable 5I.  I then rectify it as my microcontroller can't read negative voltages.

When I look at my oscilloscope after the rectifier, I'm seeing peaks of over 100V.  Upstream of the rectifier, I'm seeing a nice 5V sine wave.

## Post rectifier

[image]

## Upstream

[image]

## Circuit Diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJffBa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is the "25v AC power source" the secondary of a transformer (isolated)? Could you please post a schematic of the rectifier and how the voltage divider is connected?

Comment: Yes, it is the secondary of a transformer. I'm working on a schematic now.

Comment: @devnull uploaded a hand drawn diagram, let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks. Any other scope ground clips connected anywhere else in the circuit? Maybe even not explicitly, like through the ground pin at the primary.

Comment: Also, unrelated to the problem, since this is for measurement you may find that the voltage drop due to the diodes is excessive, specially rectifying after the voltage division, and handle the negative cycles differently.

Comment: Since you don't have a load, you have to consider the diode reverse leakage which might be lots less than O-scope input impedance. Anyhow, you don't need the diode bridge. You can add a DC offset to the signal, putting it within O-scope's range, and then remove it in software. As for the intermittent jumps, I don't have a clue. Unless there's something you haven't mentioned, I don't think anyone will.

Comment: @stretch Yes, but the voltages would not be higher than whats is found in the secondary, unless there is some coupling to the primary.

Comment: @devnull I've disconnected all other probes, still the same problem.

Comment: @MikeSchem What generates the ~300ms bursts? If you look at the first image it even looks as if it switched from full wave to half wave rectification.

Comment: @devnull what other choice do I have to measure neg voltage?

Comment: @stretch there's not too much more in the circuit, I've got an SSR turning the the primary on and off, and in parallel to the voltage divider, there's a heating element (what the circuit is actually doing).  I'll update the schematic to include these, but I didn't think they were relevant.

Comment: @devnull the 300ms bursts are generated by an STM32 connected to a zero crossing SSR. I'm adding this to my schematic.

Comment: @MikeSchem Voltage division with offset, ideal rectifier using an opamp but the rest of the circuit must be included. How is the uC powered in relation to this winding powering the heating element? Is the SSR completely isolated (opto)? No common ground/0V anywhere? If you measure the voltage directly (no isolation) there must be a known common mode. And no shorted diode... ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135057/discussion-between-mikeschem-and-devnull).

Comment: You seem to have answered your initial question yourself. The remaining issues seem to involve the bridge rectifier. You don't need it. With one more resistor and a not-very-accurate voltage source you can shift your signal into the range of o-scope. Then, in software, subtract the average value of your measurements from each of the measurements giving you a zero volt referenced data set. If you do need full-wave rectification take the absolute value of those measurements.